# Как задать двумерное зигзагообразное движение?

Tags: алгоритм, изображения

Имеется две точки — начальная и конечная. Как задать равномерное зигзагобразное движение из одной в другую?

Под равномерным подразумевается то, что волна зигзага имеет постоянную высоту и длину, и симметрична относительно прямой, соединяющей эти точки (как у синусоиды).

Comment: Уточните, что вы имеете ввиду под "равномерным зигзагообразным движением".

Comment: а то может обычный синус подойдет.

Comment: обычная синусоида подошла бы, если движение было бы относительно одной из осей, но две точки не всегда располагаются на одном и том же уровне.

Comment: а кто сказал, что синусоида может быть только относительно одной оси. Никто не мешает ее повернуть/растянуть/подрезать.

Comment: @kovadim не представляю как это сделать. Координаты синусоиды сдвигаются по обоим осям, но на какую величину?

Comment: как картинку в коментарий вставить?

Comment: Вам ещё нужно узнать, что такое "свиг и поворот системы координат". Тогда можно сделать себе такую систему координат, что первая точка будет лежать в (0,0), а вторая в (1,0). И задача  решается просто.

Но если вы используете любой серьезный движок графики, то там есть эта возможность. И как результат - сдигаете/поворачиваете систему координат и просто рисуете обычную синусоиду.

Comment: реализую на cocos2d-x на луа.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень просто.

Для начала, рассмотрим частный случай: движение из точки `(0, 0)`  в точку `(2*n*pi, 0)` по формуле

```
x = t
y = sin t
```

Такой обход делает `n` колебаний амплитудой в 1. Если мы хотим изменить амплитуду, домножим на неё: (`A` — амплитуда)

```
x = t
y = A * sin t
```

Если нам нужен отрезок длины не `2*pi*n`, а другой длины, можно «сплющить» кривую в нужное число раз: (`l` — длина отрезка)

```
x = t * l / (2 * pi * n)
y = A * sin t
```

Окей, если наш отрезок должен начинаться в точке `(x1, y1)`, перенесём нашу кривую:

```
x = x1 + t * l / (2 * pi * n)
y = y1 + A * sin t
```

Наконец, нам нужно, чтобы вектор направления был `(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)`, а у нас пока `(1, 0)`. Пусть угол поворота alpha, тогда

```
cos alpha = (x2 - x1)/l
sin alpha = (y2 - y1)/l
```

(обозначим эти величины `ca` и `sa`).

У нас получается `l = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)`.

Матрица поворота

```
 ca    sa
-sa    ca
```

Итак, имеем:

```
darg = t * l / (2 * pi * n)
dval = A * sin t
x = x1 + ca * darg + sa * dval
y = y1 - sa * darg + ca * dval
```

(`t` пробегает `0..2*n*pi`, где `n` — количество зигзагов).

Для удобства можно заменить `t -> t / (2*n*pi)`, тогда наши вычисления запишутся как

```
darg = t * l
dval = A * sin (2 * n * pi * t)
x = x1 + ca * darg + sa * dval
y = y1 - sa * darg + ca * dval
```

(здесь `t` пробегает отрезок 0..1).

Comment: @Сахарок: Угу. Там есть для него формула.

Comment: все, разобрался. Спасибо за помощь. А с поворотом объекта во время движения не поможешь? Изначально объект повернут в сторону точки

Comment: Поворот точно так же: умножаем координаты на матрицу поворота.

Поворот вокруг точки `(x0, y0)` на угол `phi`:

    xnew = x0 + (xold - x0) * cos(phi) + (yold - y0) * sin(phi)
    ynew = y0 - (xold - x0) * sin(phi) + (yold - y0) * cos(phi)

Answer (score 1):

смотрите, есть 2 точки (x1,y1) (x2, y2) надо сделать N зигзагов, при этом, движение по x и y может быть неравномерно (т.к. с равномерным мы бы не дошли)

```
dx = (x2-x1) / N
dy = (y2-y1) / N
x = x1;
y = y1;
for (i=1; i<=2*N; i++){
  if (i%2 == 0)
    x+=dx;
  else 
    y+=dy;
}
```

**p.s.** *насколько понял задачу*

**Добавлено**

Если нужно совсем равномерные зигзаги - то надо прочертить линию от точки до точки, и перпендикулярно к ней, строить зигзаги, взять ту же синусоиду, повернуть график на эту линию, и в точках максимума и минимума синусоида дорисовать вершины зигзага.

Удачи :)

1. берем линию, от точки до точки, делим ее на N четных равных отрезков (длина отрезка = D), т.е. это будут точки максимумов
2. на нечетных точках строим перпендикуляр от линии (на каждой из точек на четных по одну сторону на нечетных по другую), причем длина должна быть равна **= D * кв.корень(2)**. Это будут вершинами зигзага

Comment: зигзаг выходит, но лесенкой и не симметрично относительно прямой

Answer (score 1):

я вот тут нарисовал принцип и накидал примерный план алгоритма:

[image]

1. находим длину между красными точками
2. делим длину на количество зигзагов (волн) справа плюс два отрезка и получаем длину волны (по зеленой линии)
3. вершина волны следующей за стартовой точкой находится удаленной на половину длины волны
4. следующие вершины расчитываются равной длине волны и их количества минус одна волна
5. приходим в финишную точку

   при повернутых координатах точек надо перерасчитать их с учетом угла поворота.